# Python Scatter Plot Multiple x points and y points with same color

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Usually scatter plots use one x value, one y value. The point is colored using a z value. My scatter plot requirement is different. I have a list of x points, list of y points to be plotted using a z value or one color.
My code:

```
 samdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':[[1,2,3],4,5,6],
                     'y':[[10,20,30],40,50,60],
                     'z':[7,8,9,10]})
 plt.scatter(samdf['x'],samdf['y'],c=samdf['z'],cmap='jet')
 plt.colorbar()
 plt.show()
```

Present output:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have the reputation to comment.

The problem isn't caused by matplotplib but rather the dictionary you defined when initializing the dataframe.

You have defined your DataFrame as

```
samdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':[[1,2,3],4,5,6],
                     'y':[[10,20,30],40,50,60],
                     'z':[7,8,9,10]})
```

This is impossible each row in each column should be of a primitive type. This is equivalent to the following table:

```
x       | y          | z 
-------------------------
[1,2,3] | [10,20,30] | 7
-------------------------
4       | 40         | 8
5       | 50         | 9
...
```

which is not a valid table.

What is that dictionary even trying to achieve?